# Parsing special characters in KendoEditor TextArea

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui

I am having an issue when I insert special characters in a textarea that is rendered by a KendoEditor widget. I've configured my widget in the following way:

```
function configureRequestNotesEditor() {
$("#notes").kendoEditor({
    resizable: {
        content: true
    },
    pasteCleanup: {
        all: true,
        css: true,
        keepNewLines: true,
        msAllFormatting: true,
        msConvertLists: true,
        msTags: true,
        none: false,
        span: false
    },
    tools: [
        "bold", "underline", "insertUnorderedList", "insertOrderedList", "indent", "outdent"
    ]
});
```

};

When I send the data over to my api I use the javascript function `escape()` and when I retrieve it back from the api call the javascript function `unescape()`. The text that I am inputting into the textarea field is the following:

```
Send to James in UW ASAP.  See attached files.  How long is this field?
300
The amount should be <any amount you can think of.
```

When the data is save and then rendered back to UI the following is printed to the screen

```
<p>Send to James in UW ASAP. See attached files. How long is t his field?</p><p>300</p><p>The amount should be &lt;any amount you can think of.</p>
```

The question is, how do I get the data converted back in the same way that it was saved? What am I doing incorrectly to prevent this? Also, I forgot to mention that on the backend in C# I am using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(randomText)` before I store the text to the database.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with kendo Editor too. However I am using the ASP.NET wrapper so I will provide the way I handled it. Hope it helps.

In my editor I set

```
.Encode(false)
```

and in my Action method for the form submit I set the

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

With this two additions I didn't have to escape any characters. 
Of course this way I saved in my database the formatted text which is obviously needed in order to have the same format when I show the data to the user.